# Mule 4 failsDeployment when set to true is not failing deployment

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

We are using Mule 4. I was trying to fail the deployment when the connection check fails on http connectors and mule api connectors. I read somewhere that this will not work work in mule 4 with `<reconnection failsDeployment="true" />`. Is there another way?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Seems that you are trying to resolve some problem and using failsDeployment is most likely not going to be helpful for that. Please edit your question to clarify what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve, and provide context, code, errors, etc. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Reconnection strategies are pointless for the HTTP connector, a connector only invokes a reconnection strategy when a ConnectionException is thrown from their connect implementation, which the HTTP Connector does not.

Regardless, in most circumstances it will always be beneficial to not fail
deployment but waiting until connectivity is established later. Failing a deployment, because an external system is down does not make much sense, as there is no code or configuration change on the Mule app that will rectify the issue.

If you really need to fail a Maven build/deployment of a Mule app based an external connection working though, you can use MUnit to write an a test/integration test that performs the connection/request you are expecting and assert it works. If not the test will fail and the Maven build will fail. You can tag this test as an integration test and only run it from a specific build phase if necessary.